# What's the best jQuery product zoom plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, e-commerce, zooming

I'm not much of a frontend guy, just learning jQuery, so any help is appreciated. What's the easiest, most stable jQuery zoom plugin?

I have a regular size product image and a detailed image. I need to be able to zoom in somehow. Which would you recommend?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[jqzoom](http://www.mind-projects.it/projects/jqzoom/)

[fancyzoom](http://www.dfc-e.com/metiers/multimedia/opensource/jquery-fancyzoom/)

Comment: It is driving me crazy though that I the zoomWidth changes seem to have no effect. The lens is way too tiny and the zoomed window is too small...nothing I do seems to have any impact...any thought?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't done this. Just had a look at this and thought it might be useful.

Comment: Fixed it...it's a bit janky when resizing windows and chrome needs reboot after a refresh, but I guess it works ok overall.

Comment: jqzoom doesn't work on mobile devices (at least not on my iPhone or iPad). Just fyi.

Answer (score 3):

See also:

[Anything Zoomer](http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingZoomer/index.html)

[Magnify](http://www.jnathanson.com/index.cfm?page=jquery/magnify/magnify#examples)

[Mag View](http://www.uize.com/examples/mag-view.html)

[Whole bunch of them](http://www.downloadjavascripts.com/Zoom%20And%20Magnifiers.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, but my question was aiming more for best of breed recommendations from experienced front end developers than trying out a list of different ones. Which of those would you recommend to a client or friend? 

jqzoom installed OK, but the dimensions aren't working for me, unless I can figure out why my settings aren't taking I'll have to choose another one.

Comment: Each solution has it's ups and downs. Sometimes you hit a roadblock and there's no explanation why. I ran into this issue with a a jquery "endless scrolling" plugin the other day. Contacted the developer to let him know and didn't get anything back. So I was forced to find another solution. No problem. Installation is a matter of popping in a javascript file and renaming a few classes. Therefore, I've always went about trying each one, considering you're looking at only a matter of a few minutes per install. I typically look for a solution that 1) Works (in all browsers) 2) is extendable.

Comment: I would say jqzoom is the most popular and most widely accepted among all of those examples.

Answer (score 2):

check CloudZoom: the best, imo http://www.professorcloud.com/mainsite/cloud-zoom.htm

Answer (score 1):

check AJAX-ZOOM: http://www.ajax-zoom.com/index.php?cid=examples

Answer (score 0):

What about zooma? Check it here:
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/zooma