# how to zoom in an image using jquery

Tags: jquery, zooming

I was just wondering how it's possible to zoom in a pic using jquery,

something like this web site,

[link text](http://www.asos.com/Asos-Collection/Asos-Waffle-Shawl-Collar-Cardigan/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=822830&cid=6993&sh=0&pge=0&pgesize=20&sort=-1&clr=Grey)

when you click on the big image it'll zoom in and you can move your cursor and see the other part of the pic while zoomed in,

I'd appreciate it if someone could show me a link or put me in the right direction.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

They don't zoom in, what is really happening is that when you click the Zoom text, the image inside the div is replaced by a larger version of that image. And overflow is set to hidden.

As you move your cursor, using some clever JavaScript and DOM handling, the image is simply moved relatively accordingly, creating the effect you are actually zooming in the picture.

I'll try to create up a simple example for you.

**EDIT**

Sorry took a while but here it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
                var fullWidth = 864; // Width in pixels of full-sized image
                var fullHeight = 648; // Height in pixels of full-sized image
                var thumbnailWidth = 389;  // Width in pixels of thumbnail image
                var thumbnailHeight = 292;  // Height in pixels of thumbnail image

                // Set size of div
                $('#picture').css({
                        'width': thumbnailWidth+'px',
                        'height': thumbnailHeight+'px'
                });

                // Hide the full-sized picture
                $('#full').hide();

                // Toggle pictures on click
                $('#picture').click(function() {
                        $('#thumbnail').toggle();
                        $('#full').toggle();
                });

                // Do some calculations
                $('#picture').mousemove(function(e) {
                        var mouseX = e.pageX - $(this).attr('offsetLeft'); 
                        var mouseY = e.pageY - $(this).attr('offsetTop'); 

                        var posX = (Math.round((mouseX/thumbnailWidth)*100)/100) * (fullWidth-thumbnailWidth);
                        var posY = (Math.round((mouseY/thumbnailHeight)*100)/100) * (fullHeight-thumbnailHeight);

                        $('#full').css({
                                'left': '-' + posX + 'px',
                                'top': '-' + posY + 'px'
                        });
                });
        });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        #picture {
                overflow: hidden;
                position: relative;
                border: 1px solid #000000;
        }

        #thumbnail {
                cursor: pointer;
        }

        #full {
                position: relative;
                cursor: crosshair;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="picture">
        <img alt="" id="thumbnail" src="http://img202.imageshack.us/img202/8403/93629325.jpg" />
        <img alt="" id="full" src="http://img111.imageshack.us/img111/4734/tbmecsekyellowflower.jpg" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You will need to adjust the thumbnail and full-sized image width and height accordingly. But simply copy paste the above to see an example of an image hosted on imageshack.

Comment: Working on it, give me a couple of mins.

Comment: this does not seem to play well if the image is nested inside an absolute positioned element, as offsetLeft and offsetTop dont work.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

The gzoom, miniZoomPan, WarpZoom, and Image Detail plugins all make this sort of thing easy. You can find them all here:

http://plugins.jquery.com/taxonomy/term/1848

There are probably others too.

Hope that helps!

EDIT: There are several more listed on a previous question called [What’s the best jQuery product zoom plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276048/whats-the-best-jquery-product-zoom-plugin)

Comment: Good find, No Surprises (np pun intended :P)

Answer (score 1):

What you need is not just plain zooming. But a zoom and pan function within a fixed viewport. The website you gave probably code it from scratch. I found one for you which is not exactly the same, but you might want totake a look [here](http://www.netzgesta.de/shiftzoom/).

Meanwhile, I'm eager to see what Sbm007's example.

Comment: Since you said you're interested in my example, thought I'd let you know that I've edited my post to include it.

Comment: @Sbm007: Didn't test it but can tell that you did some intensive work. Looks pretty cool. Nice work!

Answer (score 0):

Asos.com coded theirs from scratch, see how with Firebug: http://www.asos.com/assets/asosCom/js/libs/asos.js.utils.productpage.js

Answer (score 0):

Hey amir I am adding one tutorial link and it's  proper solution for your search, try tutorial from following link, it will also help you for zoom in image in 3 other different ways...

http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/

i had tried this and it's working fine.