# jQuery modal style box image zoomer

Tags: jquery, zooming

Does anyone know how to do the Asos style:

http://www.asos.com/ASOS/ASOS-Overdyed-Marl-Zip-Through-Hoodie/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=1787623&cid=5668&sh=0&pge=0&pgesize=20&sort=-1&clr=Red+marl

And the Amazon style:

http://www.amazon.co.uk/ZANNA-SWAROVSKI-DRESS-Midnight-Blue/dp/B0050HK3TQ/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&m=A1RKWVIPB0RYS4&s=generic&qid=1315477712&sr=1-3

product zoom effects via jquery?

if you click the image, a div box comes up covering most the page content and overlaying a dark effect around content allowing a scroll up or down effect...

Thanks

Comment: My question has been answered before on Stack: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581784/how-to-zoom-in-an-image-using-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many open-source Javascript/Jquery plugins for that procedure. For example: 1.Lightbox 2, see demo here: http://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/ 2.Fancybox: http://fancybox.net/ 3.Thickbox: http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/ 4.Colorbox: http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/ and many others. If you want to create the procedure by yourself read some tutorials about Jquery modal windows. The main idea is to create centered div which contains the image and close buton.

Comment: No but I want the ASOS style product image zoom - as soon as the modal opens the image is fully overlapping and you can move up and down...